# Intellij Live Template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, live-templates

Is there any way to use a default token value in Intellij `Live templates`? For example I have the following live template which declares a private variable that I would like to create nearly for every class:

`private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger($CLASS$.class)`

It seems unnecessary to type `$CLASS$` every time when this live template is used, because it can be derived from the class in scope or filename. I was wondering if it is possible to use environment defined tokens in live templates as defaults?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Check some other templates that already use the current class name:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, where all available expressions are defined?

Comment: All of the expressions are listed here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html

Answer (score 55):

log4j:

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);
```

slf4j:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);
```

Make sure that you set the **applicable context** to Java and that **shorten FQ names** and **skip if defined** are enabled.

Comment: I like the addition this article mentions for setting up en expression to populate the variable with a sensible default. 

https://coderwall.com/p/hzmhbw

Comment: @Snekse That's a good addition. You are welcome to improve my answer by editing it.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the questioner's question: to auto-fill the `$CLASS_NAME$` variable with the class name you need to set the "Expression" associated to the `$CLASS_NAME$` variable to be `className()`. See CrazyCoder's answer for a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

log4j 2:

```java
private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger($CLASS_NAME$.class);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the questioner's question: to auto-fill the `$CLASS_NAME$` variable with the class name you need to set the "Expression" associated to the `$CLASS_NAME$` variable to be `className()`. See CrazyCoder's answer for a screenshot.