# How to enter logger definition in IntelliJ fast?

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea, live-templates

Are there some live template or something, to add logger definition into a class?

In Eclipse I had a template:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(${enclosing_type}.class);
```

Don't see something about this in [Log Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4953).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097646/intellij-live-template

Answer (score 29):

Using IntelliJ Live Template:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates
```

Setting like below:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger($CLASSNAME$.class);
```

[image]

To expand a code snippet, type "**logger**" and press **Tab**

Comment: As I was landing here because i searched that for Kotlin: Note that you need to use kotlinClassName() with Kotlin

Answer (score 24):

I am using this live template:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger( $CLASSNAME$.class );
```

Go to "Edit variables" and set the `CLASSNAME` variable to be the expression `className()` so IntelliJ will automatically insert the class name.

Further, enable the checkbox 'Shorten FQ names' so IntelliJ will use import statements.

Comment: The best solution.

Answer (score 4):

you can add template by adding following code in:

`Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> class`

`private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(${NAME}.class);`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/)? It's not a live template, but it helps with a lot of boilerplate code (getters/setters, equals, hash codes, loggers...)

To create a logger, annotate your class with `@Log`/`@Slf4j`/`@CommonsLog` and Lombok will create a static field `log` for you to use.

It plays well with IntelliJ - IDE plugin will inject the bolierplate code in your class during compilation phase while keeping your sources lean.

Comment: Basically a few of the things Kotlin does anyway for a java developer.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default but you can create a new one with the live template:

See this: 
[Intellij Live Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097646/intellij-live-template)