# Is there a way to automatiically print a log debug statement on a variable?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am looking at live templates in IntelliJ IDEA and I wanted to know whether there is a way to  `log.debug()` a variable quickly.

Let's say I want:

```
var myValue = 10;
log.debug("myValue=" + myValue);
```

I have `log.debug("" + $STRING$);` in the live template, but this will force me to include the variable name and text manually.  Does IntelliJ have the ability to log a variable that directly precedes my cursor?  Or through some other action?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058864/how-to-enter-logger-definition-in-intellij-fast) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `soutv` Java template as an example:

```
System.out.println("$EXPR_COPY$ = " + $EXPR$);
```

Where `$EXPR$` is defined as `variableOfType("")` with `"expr"` default value
and `$EXPR_COPY$` is defined as `escapeString(EXPR)`.

Documentation for `variableOfType()` states:

> variableOfType()   Returns all variables that may be assigned
> to the type passed as the parameter. For example,
> variableOfType("double"), variableOfType("java.util.Vector"), or
> variableOfType(methodReturnType()).
>
> If you pass an empty string "" as the parameter, the function suggests
> all variables regardless of their types.

So, all you need to do is to make the similar template but use `log.debug` instead of `System.out.println`.